# how to get silent installation status of application

Tags: macos, installation, silent

I am installing an application on Mac using silent installation. The problem here is I want to read/get the status of application installaton, I mean whether it is installed succesfully or not. Tried with redirecting console output to some text file but its not working.

I tried like,

```
./installer -s -v > logfile
```

it is showing output on console but not redirecting to the logfile.

Comment: What version of OSX is this? There is no `-s` option currently, and you always require `-target` and `-pkg` parameters. It is also very strange that you would include `./` at the beginning. What directory are you in when you run this? I'm not seeing any trouble redirecting output to a logfile on 10.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
./installer -s -v 2>&1 logfile
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. I tried something like ./installer -s -v 2>&1 | tee logfile and i am able to redirect console o/p to logfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try `./installer -s -v &> logfile` or `./installer -s -v 2> logfile`